# Clean up index files and place in directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory-structure

Right now I have a assortment of 9 files (javascript, image, stylesheet, php) in the root directory of my web server. I would like too put all of these files in a directory called `home` (for home page). So now at this point I can view my home page at `http://example.com/home`.

I would like it so that when you visit `http://example.com/` it points to the files in the home directory.

I am using php so my first attempt was to create a `index.php` in the root and include the index from home. This breaks relative URLS within styles, javascript, and includes. To combat this I prepended my includes with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/home/`. More problems arise when I try to redirect `http://example.com/home` to `http://example.com/`.

Is their any better way of doing this, possibly with `.htaccess`?

Comment: Why not have `example.com/` redirect to `example.com/home`? Of course, this just opens a can of worms. Now you've got 9 files littering up the `home` directory, and you'll want `/home/home` and so on...

Comment: I want the domain to show as example.com/, redirecting doesn't seam viable.

Comment: Then use mod_rewrite to change hits on `/` to `/home`. But then you'll most likely lose the ability to host any OTHER content in `/` outside of that `/home` subdir.

Comment: Marc B has a valid point. How is having 9 files in `/home` any better than having them in `/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if your server supports mod_rewrite, you could probably add a RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule /(.*) /home/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: ... and have a rewrite loop and, as a result, an error page. You need at least add a condition to not to rewrite already rewritten URLs.

Answer (score 2):

In your Apache httpd.conf change the DocumentRoot to your "home" folder.

Comment: i guess this is the best solution, if you have different sites you could create apache virtual servers